# How to tell Drools to "JIT"-compile all the MVEL to Java?

Tags: drools

Drools has a JIT feature, which I've found to be counter-productive for my use-case, it's not aggressive enough about compiling the MVEL into Java. How can I configure it to compile as much as possible as early as possible?

Comment: I don't think that the premise of your question is correct. Where did you find that "Drools (!) has a JIT feature" (as opposed to Java's JIT) and that MVEL is compiled into Java (!). - There's a number of "Advanced JIT Compiler Options" for java (the program) but you haven't asked about that.

Comment: I found out by stepping through the Drools code. The first line in `org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint.evaluate` deals with the JIT. After some more digging I found out it's hard-coded to 20 iterations before the MVEL-to-Java JIT translation.  (it's a JIT translation, not to be confused with the JVM JIT compiler)

Comment: The output would be Java byte code, not Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not configurable and is hard-coded to the value 20 (number of iterations before JIT occurs) in `org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint`, line 63 (in version 6.2.0.Final):

```
protected static final int JIT_THRESOLD = 20; // Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

After additional investigation it turns out I found no reason to change this setting. YMMV.